# git rollback in real world, in work situation

Tags: git

Currently,I have a git repository like below:
[image]

In the past I commit many features until N and merge into release branch more than once. But now I do not want to release any of it, So I like rollback my feature branch to commit 2, since there are so many commits and merge commits, I can not use a `revert` or `revert range`. So how to make those changes affect to the release branch? the release branch is a public branch and can not be do reset.I think The ideal scenario is make the commit 2 as a new commit next to N, and just do a merge request, any way can do it?

Comment: Release branch does not already contain commits 1,2,... N right? And you ONLY want to merge commits 1 and 2?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I didn't notice the "many merge" part of the diagram

Comment: So all you want is to bring commit 2 to your release branch and get rid of 2 ... N? Cherry pick that commit on the release branch? You cannot and should not change history. So why would you want to delete the history of your merges in the release branch?